# NetSuite modify packing slip URL

Tags: netsuite

in netsuite how can I modify the URL below so that it can display packing slip based on multiple ID. as example I want new window to display packing slip for id= 366646 and id=361518 on the same window. is this possible?

https://system.netsuite.com/app/accounting/print/hotprint.nl?regular=T&sethotprinter=T&id=366646&label=Picking+Ticket&printtype=pickingticket&trantype=trnfrord&whence=&print=T

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to print multiple picking tickets by default as the hotprint function can only process one ID at a time. You could do the following:

1. Build a suitelet that can handle both ID's and use the hotprint for each.
2. Merge the two resulting PDF's together and display that in a popup window.

I will dig around for an example code I did for multiple sales orders.